# Vulkan - How to know what is current image layout?

Tags: image, layout, transition, vulkan

After rendering or some other actions, I want to read the target image into cpu.
For this, there is need first to do layout transition and change the image's current layout (old layout ) to a new one that allows transferring its data into stage image - VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_SRC_OPTIMAL.

For transition operation, I need to give both, the current layout and the new layout.

But how do I know what is the current layout ? - each render pass may set the finalLayout to a different value, it also may that some transitions where done by the time.

A solution I think is to store per image its current layout and set it after each render pass , and after each transition operation.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> But how do I know what is the current layout ? - each render pass may set the finalLayout to a different value, it also may that some transitions where done by the time.

Yes, but *you* created those render passes. You issued commands to use those render passes on that image. Therefore, at any point in the command stream, you know what layout the image is in.

Vulkan expects you to be aware of what you've done. How you pull that off is up to you. Maybe you always leave the image in color-attachment optimal. Maybe you explicitly keep track of it with some higher-level layer. It could be any number of things.

But at the end of the day, it's up to you. With great power, comes great responsibility.